# convert.toByte rounds float number

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that works on a big matrix. Due to the lack of memory, I defined the matrix as `byte[]`. The problem of lack of memory was resolved, but now when I want to assign values to the elements of the matrix, it tells me that float values can not be converted to byte(the values of elements are float). So, using `Convert.ToByte` I converted float values to byte. The problem is that it rounds the float values and I don't want it. Is there any function that I can use and it does not round the float number?
a portion of code is as follow:

```
static byte[,,] Score = new byte[1501,1501,501];
Score[i, j, att] = Convert.ToByte(2.0 *(Math.Log(calNum())));
```

where `calnum` is a function that calculates a float number

Comment: I think something is missing there... if you need to store X floats, you cannot use an array of X bytes for it. And if you are using an array of 4X bytes, why not define it as an array of X floats?

Comment: because I face the lack of memory once I am running the program, I can not define the matrix as float. so, I defined it as byte[]

Comment: The downvoters presumably do not remember the time, early in their programming journey, when they first attempted to do something impossible...

Comment: If there was any way by which you could use a `byte` to represent a `float` with the same precission, programming languages would be already using that technique instead of wasting so much memory, wouldn't they? Partition the array into chunks, keep in memory one chunk and store in disk the others, or even use a DB to store the array.

Comment: @CodeCaster to me it both shows research effort and is clear (enough that I can tell what the problem is, anyway), making enough reason for an upvote. YMMV, of course.

Comment: So ... because you don't have enough RAM to store your values in a float, you convert them to byte and wonder where the rest of your data went?

Comment: yes, but I think this is the only way I can use

Comment: @mary however you encode it, one byte can only contain a limited range of numbers. If that's too limited for your use, then you're out of luck. Consider an alternative approach altogether.

Comment: I do not need the numbers have high precision. just one digit after point is enough. for example 2.1 is enough. is there any way not to use float type for the matrix?

Comment: Depending on the range, you could simply use a byte and divide its value by 10 while performing calculations on it, giving you a range of 0-25.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible technicaly. See here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

It's actualy possible, but, well, if you want to store numbers like from -5 to 5 with some low accuracy.

If you work with math, you probably need to see in direction of **sparse matrix**.
This matrix will optimize its internal representation with less memory impact.

Comment: yes, you'r right. but, processing sparse matrices are very difficult

Comment: in which aspect it is difficult?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using decimal instead of float. Depending upon the number of decimals places you are trying to use, float might try to round off or even might give unreliable result. Please read further to understand difference between float, double and decimal at the below link. Hope it helps.

[Difference between decimal float and double in net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Comment: no, I should assign float numbers to the elements of the matrix and because I defined the matrix as byte[], it can not convert float numbers to byte. so, i used convert.tobyte() to convert float numbers. float numbers are calculated autommatically

Comment: If he will use decimal he will fall into pit of even bigger memory problems.